# Callback query телеграм php?

Tags: php, api, telegram, бот

я использую https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

```
include('vendor/autoload.php');
use Telegram\Bot\Api;
use Telegram\Bot\Keyboard\Keyboard;

  $api = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  $telegram = new Api($api);
  $result = $telegram->getWebhookUpdates();
  $result = json_decode($result, True);
  $text = $result["message"]["text"];
  $chat_id = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"];
  $update = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
  $query = $update->getCallbackQuery();
  $callback_id = $query->getId();

if($text == '/start' OR $text == $backbutton){
  $inline_keyboard = Keyboard::make(['resize_keyboard' => true])
    ->row(
      Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => "Қазақша",'callback_data' => "kaz"]),
      Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => "Русский",'callback_data' => 'rus']),
    );
    
 $telegram->sendMessage([
  'chat_id' => $chat_id, 
  'text' => 'xxxxxx', 
  'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
  'reply_markup' => $inline_keyboard,
  ]);
} 
if($callback_id == 'kaz') {
      $inline_keyboard_one = Keyboard::make(['resize_keyboard' => true])
    ->row(
      Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => '123','callback_data' => "prod"]),
    );
 $telegram->sendMessage([
  'chat_id' => $chat_id, 
  'text' => 'xxxxxx', 
  'parse_mode' => 'HTML', 
  'reply_markup' => $inline_keyboard_one, 
  ]);
}
```

не работает помогите плиз?????

Comment: "Не работает" понятие растяжимое. Ошибки, ошибки в логах где? Экстрасенсы в отпуске

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [`westacks/telebot`](https://github.com/westacks/telebot):

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WeStacks\TeleBot\Objects\Update;
use WeStacks\TeleBot\TeleBot;

$bot = new TeleBot('123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11');

// Start command
$bot->addHandler(function (Update $update) use ($bot) {
    if (!$message = $update->message()) return;
    if ($message->text != '/start') return;

    return $bot->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $update->chat()->id,
        'text' => 'Test',
        'reply_markup' => [
            'inline_keyboard' => [[
                ['text' => "Қазақша", 'callback_data' => "lang:kaz"],
                ['text' => "Русский", 'callback_data' => 'lang:rus'],
            ]]
        ]
    ]);
});

// Language callback
$bot->addHandler(function (Update $update) use ($bot) {
    if (!$query = $update->callback_query ?? false) return;
    if (!str_contains($query->data, 'lang:')) return;

    $lang = explode(':', $query->data)[1];

    return $bot->answerCallbackQuery([
        'callback_query_id' => $query->id,
        'text' => 'Your language is: ' . $lang,
        'show_alert' => true
    ]);
});

// Handling bot updates
echo 'Bot is working...'.PHP_EOL;

$last_offset = 0;
while (true) {
    $updates = $bot->getUpdates([
        'offset' => $last_offset + 1
    ]);
    foreach ($updates as $update) {
        echo "Update recieved: $update->update_id" . PHP_EOL;
        $bot->handleUpdate($update);
        $last_offset = $update->update_id;
    }
}
```